# GAE datastore encoding issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding, google-cloud-datastore, parse-platform

In GAE I save some entities, than upon a servlet request I send a request with the saved data to Parse and it sends push notification with the data to whole the relevant clients.
The problem I'm having is that GAE sends the data to Parse with wrong encoding. I did add encoding before sending to parse.

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL urlObject = new URL(PUSH_URL);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", APPLICATION_ID);
    connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", REST_API_KEY);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "utf-8");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.getOutputStream().write(payload.getBytes());
```

P.S.
I also had this problem when working with the local GAE instance, but it was fixed when I changed the Eclipse's IDE encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default system (JVM) encoding on GAE is US-ASCII. Since `string.getBytes()` encodes a string using system encoding you do not get what you expect - UTF-8.

On GAE you need to explicitly set encoding - use `getBytes("UTF-8")` instead.